# Contr.sums and contr.poly question?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I know that `contr.poly` creates orthogonal polynomials of degree 1, 2, etc. so that you can determine if there is a particularly mathematical pattern (e.g., linear, quadratic, cubic, etc.). And, `contr.sum` provides orthogonal contrasts where you compare every level to the overall mean.

Are categorical variables always coded with `contr.sum`? And continuous with `contr.poly`? How do you know which one you should use to specify your variable?

Comment: It's a little bit more complex.  It depends on what you want to compare. https://rpubs.com/monajhzhu/608609